# Experienced Windows programmer wants to learn Linux programming

Tags: linux, windows

Experienced Windows programmer wants to learn Linux programming.
I have a Windows 7 machine. No Linux installed yet.
I have to learn from scratch including installation and then programming.
I have been programming in C/C++ for lots of years - nothing to learn here.
Just the Linux stuff.
Any good tutorials that match the situation?
How long should it take?

Comment: Why was that downvoted ?

Comment: @Gcmalloc probably because in doesn't follow the guidelines for a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: VMware or VirtualBox, install a Linux guest on your Windows box, then use one or more of the hundreds of books and/or thousands of web articles. It should take somewhere between a day and the rest of your life depending on how deep you want to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get used to a linux environement, I think you should first get a live CD/USB of any [Linux distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) that you want. By example you can follow [this tutorial for Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) or [this one for Fedora](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Live_USB).

Then, you can open a terminal and follow another tutorial like [this one](http://www.linfo.org/create_c1.html), to start programming on Linux.

Finally, if you need to install the Linux distribution, you should know that nowadays every good Linux distribution have a very easy installer directly available from their live CD/USB. Just put your basic configuration and click next !

Comment: Why was that downvoted ?

Comment: Can I install those (Ubuntu, etc) under or alongside Windows without a virtual machine?

Comment: Yes, normally this option is suggested during the installation. After this you will have a "dual-boot" where you can choose between your Linux distrib or Windows.